# Solution For Bypassing a Step: Text To CSV Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

1. I read text file with header=None because first 6 lines are unnecessary and becoming obstacle in using '|' as delimiter. Because I need to convert text file in csv file.
2. Then I need to convert that file into csv file and I again need to import 27evening.csv file by using delimiter '|'. Then only I can save df2 as final csv.

I don not want to save(as csv) after 4th step shown in figure and want to open userhistory_aam.txt by using delimiter "|".
Here I don't want to generate unnecessary middle file(27evening.csv) Can you please provide alternative.

'''

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("userhistory_aam[50][100]27May.txt", header = None)
df.columns = [''] * len(df.columns)
df.drop([0,1,2,3,4,6],0,inplace=True)
df.to_csv("27evening.csv", index = None)
df2 = pd.read_csv("27evening.csv", delimiter = '|')
df2.to_csv('final.csv')
```

'''

Comment: please don't post pictures of code

Comment: @Isotope Ok I am removing

Comment: @Isotope Without removing first 6 lines I am not able to convert text file into csv file using delimiter as '|'. Hence I have to save txt file after removing first 6 lines. But I need to bypass this step because it is generating unnecessary 27evening.csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `skiprows` in your read method.

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt',sep='|',skiprows=6)
```

#### `data.txt.`

```
 random text and data
# could also start with a #
more random text 
1|2|3|4|5|6|7
1|2|3|4|5|6|7
1|2|3|4|5|6|7
A|B|C|D|E|F|G # <-- data starts here.
a|b|c|d|e|f|g
```

---

```
print(df)

   A  B  C  D  E  F   G
0  a  b  c  d  e  f  g
```

---

Note `# <-- data starts here.` is just for illustration, don't put that into your text file.